# Do you map EntityObjects to your domain objects?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, architecture

Is it considered as a good practice to map all the objects that we receive from Entity Framework to domain objects?

I mean this always leads to a huge amount of mapping code, which have got to be updated manually every time we need a new property. That seems like unnecessary work.

Besides we loose some of the benefits of Entity Framework. For example:
- EntityObject has useful property EntityState. 
- You get easy and eager loading out of box.
It is possible to implement this for your domain objects as well, but it is an additional work.

What benefits does mapping to domain objects give? What are the disadvantages?

Comment: Try automapper (http://automapper.org/) it will remove the unneccessary mapping code. I like mapping the entity objects to BO objects it lets you seperate the concerns and change the BO objects or entity objects without worrying about dependancies. It also lets you use Dependancy Injection.

Comment: @gh9 have you read [this post](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/)?  
I see people on StackOverflow referencing to it, saying that two-way binding using AutoMapper is not a good thing. I don't think I'm getting it, so It would be great to hear your oppinion.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I understand both sides of the argument. To sum up my opinion on it, I dislike the idea of having the domain model directly be influenced by the UI Model( or whatever you are mapping). I understand why people wnat that seeing as how it would make life easier. I guess it just depends on your personal tastes